# Visual studio Windows Form designer error: "Construction of frame content failed."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

After I added a `UserControl` to my `Form` it suddenly started to produce this error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

So I googled around and found out it is somehow related to cache. So I deleted `suo` file from my solution. And now it produces this error:

> Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

I googled that too and found out I should read the contents of the `ActivityLog.xml` which can be found in `%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`. It starts with this message:

> Construction of frame content failed.

I couldn't find any solution any further.

here is the complete error from that log:

> Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier:
>   ST:0:0:{31fc2115-5126-4a87-b2f7-77eaab65048b} Frame caption: Exception
>   details: System.ArgumentNullException: Parameter name: protocolHandler
>   at
>   Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.UI.LivePropertyExplorer.Model.PropertyExplorerModel..ctor(IProtocolHandler
>   protocolHandler, IActiveElementTracker tracker, ITelemetryLogger
>   telemetryLogger) at
>   Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.Model.XamlDiagnosticsTool.GetPropertyExplorerModel(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider) at
>   Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.Model.XamlDiagnosticsTool.CreatePropertyExplorer(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, ResourceDictionary themeDictionary, UIElement
>   searchContentControl) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.XamlDiagnostics.PropertyExplorerToolWindow.GetContent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.XamlDiagnostics.XamlDiagnosticsToolWindowBase.ShowContent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.XamlDiagnostics.XamlDiagnosticsToolWindowBase.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.InternalSetSite(IServiceProvider
>   p) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsWindowPane.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   psp) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.WindowPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIElementPane.SetUIElementSite(IServiceProvider
>   p) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.UIElementDocumentObject.SetSite(DocumentObjectSite
>   site) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DocumentObjectSite.InitializeDocumentObject(Object
>   punkView) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.CreateContentPane(FrameMoniker
>   frameMoniker, Boolean isDocument, String lpstrMkDoc, UInt32
>   eCreateWindowFlags, Object punkView, Object punkData, IServiceProvider
>   pServiceProvider, IVsUIHierarchy pUIHierarchy, UInt32 vsid, Guid
>   rguidCmdUI, ViewGroup parent, IVsWindowFrame& ppWindowFrame) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.CreateContentPane(String
>   pszName, Int32 fDockViewOn, Int32 fDocument, String lpstrMkDoc, UInt32
>   eCreateWindowFlags, UInt32 dwToolWinId, Object punkView, Object
>   punkData, IServiceProvider pServiceProvider, IVsUIHierarchy
>   pUIHierarchy, UInt32 vsid, Int32& pfDefaultPosition, Guid& rguidCmdUI,
>   IVsWindowFrame& ppWindowFrame) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type
>   toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type
>   toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type
>   toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute
>   tool) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid&
>   toolWindowType, Int32 id) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid&
>   toolWindowType, UInt32 id) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()

What's going on? What does `Construction of frame content failed` mean?

Comment: Probably that the designer is trying to draw a rendering of your usercontrol and is experiencing an error (from your control) while doing so

Comment: @CaiusJard You're right, I just noticed a warning saying there's a conflict between the usercontrol and exactly the same usercontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Caius I managed to find the problem. The designer was unable to render the `Form` because of an error regarding the `UserControl`. I looked into the designer.cs file and find a warning saying that there is a conflict between `UserControl` [version] in [path] and `UserControl` in [path].

I looked into the references of the project and found a self-reference there! So I removed it and the error went away.

The `UserControl` and `Form` were in the same project and while adding the `UserControl` to the `Form` I drag-and-dropped the `UserControl` from the `Toolbox` onto the `Form`. So it automatically added a self-reference to my project. I'm not sure why it did that. But removing the reference solved the issue.